# Issues with Alamofire Request in Swift using Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Could someone help this newbie with a question. I have created the following class

```
import Foundation

class Search {

var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var dob: String


init(firstName: String, lastName: String, dob: String)
{

    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.dob = dob
}

}
```

I have then imported Alamofire into my swift project as i want to make a json request to a rest web service.

This is my request

```
let searchParameters = Search(firstName: "frankie", lastName: "jones",dob: "09-08-1995")

    request(.GET, "http://blahblahblah/get", parameters: searchParameters)
       .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)
```

So why am I getting the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'response' with an argument list of type ((*,*,_))->)'??

Any Ideas?
Thx

Comment: i think the problem is with your parameters i.e. how you sending it...try using simple declaration first like `let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]` and check

Comment: Thanks for reply. @Bhavin Your above solution is fine but my rest service accepts an object in the format that I am trying to pass. Surely it's common practice to pass an object to a rest service? I have a friend who is using JavaScript who passes an object using I think it's called stringify to the same rest service with no issue, surely swift is based on JavaScript so someone must have this implemented? Please help lol :)

Comment: If you could post a cURL example of what you're expecting to occur, it would be easier to assist. Also, as @Bhavin mentioned, your `searchParameters` need to be in the form of a dictionary, not a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking can't handle your Search object. Convert it to a dictionary and pass the dictionary representation into the request method.